# In Jasmine, how do I stub out a spied upon method?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I would like to stub out a function in addition to spying on it in Jasmine. How can I do this?

```
var o = { foo: function(){} };
var spy = spyOn(o, 'foo')
  .andStubWith(function() { console.log('foo'); }); // This is pseudocode - is there a real equivalent?
```

The reason I dont want to simply overwrite the function in my test is that IIUC, Jasmine will undo any spies after each test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_`and.callFake`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callFake%3C/code%3E)

```
spyOn(o, "foo").and.callFake(function() {
  console.log('foo')
  return 1001;
});
```